# Tesseract "estimating resolution as 304" line prints word by word + takes >1 second to print. Why and how to supress?

Tags: c++, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

```
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
    if (tess.Init("./languages/fast/", "eng"))
    {
        std::cout << "OCRTesseract: Could not initialize tesseract." << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }
    tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PageSegMode::PSM_AUTO);
    tess.SetVariable("save_best_choices", "T");
    tess.SetVariable("user_defined_dpi", "70");
    auto buffer = ocrQueue.getBuffer();

    tess.SetImage((const unsigned char*)buffer->data(), buffer->getWidth(), buffer->getHeight(), 3, buffer->getWidth()*3);
    tess.Recognize(0);

    std::cout << tess.GetUTF8Text() << std::endl;
```

Everytime this code runs I get

```
Estimating resolution as 304
```

which takes >1 second to print, and prints word by word, which is annoying.

How to supress this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tess.SetVariable("user_defined_dpi", "71");
```

or

```
tess.SetVariable("debug_file", "/dev/null");
```